# buttons disappearing from a linear layout

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, textview, tableview

I have a complicated linear layout, with some buttons and edittext:

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="400dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:text="@string/stop"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:hint="@string/hint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/choose"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:minWidth="150dp"
            android:textSize="10sp"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:hint="@string/favourites"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/choose"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/text3"
                android:hint="@string/clean"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/choose"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:text="@string/request"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text2"
            android:onClick="lookUp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            />


        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#3d455b"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button">

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/hscrll1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >


                    <TableLayout
                        android:id="@+id/table_main"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
                        android:stretchColumns="2">
                    </TableLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Everything looks at it should on a large screen (tablet): I have the first line with the edittext and two buttons, on the line below I have the other button, and below it I have the scrollview (with the table).
When I switch to normal screen (smartphone), only the first line is appearing, the rest not being visible.
What could the solution be?

Comment: Your layout is large enough. it will not come into mobile screen. you should put whole layout into scrollview

Comment: do you mean to add a scrollview which surrounds the linear layout?

Comment: yes as a parent of whole layout not in between

Comment: android:layout_marginBottom="400dp" its should be based screen density

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Small Screen device there are problem with margin you set, try to
remove `android:layout_marginBottom="400dp"` from your `ParentLayout` and manage your `Layout` according them

Comment: @helius83 always wlc

Answer (score 0):

At the second linear_layout (that have horizontal orientation) all of your views, have match parent width that cause non of them are visible. I think it's what you want:

`

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:minWidth="150dp"
        android:textSize="10sp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:hint="@string/favourites"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        androidlayout_weight = "1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textSize="10sp"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:hint="@string/clean"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight = "1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            />
 </LinearLayout>
```

`